# Unhide all selected

Tags: objects, 3d-view

If you have multiple models selected, you can hide them all at once with 'H' or by Alt-clicking on the Eye icon in the outliner. However, there does not seem to be any way to unhide only the selected objects without unhiding everything. Alt-clicking on the Eye again only unhides the specific object you're clicking on.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively simple to do with a bit of Python code:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if not ob.select:
        continue
    ob.hide = False
```

You can paste this into a text editor in Blender and run it, or extend it into an add-on with an operator and a button to add to your user interface.

Comment: So if I just want to unhide all, Alt+H, what's the equivalent code for that?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Edit > Preferences > Keymap
Untick all the "Select".

This way when you unhide any geometry, it won't be selected anymore.